# Equivalent to GetExternalAuthenticationTypes() in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've spent a long time trying to convert an ASP.NET 5.0 app to ASP.NET Core 2 and I just can't find a few things.  I'm trying to get the list of external providers (Google, Facebook, etc.) that are supported by the current installation.  Pre Core, I would have used:

```
Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes()
```

Of course, I can't use that anymore due to the OWIN reference, but I haven't been able to find a similar function anywhere else either.  I don't want to have to set it manually.  Is there a sample of using this to create a nice social login page?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you looked into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/ ?

Comment: I've read through that any many other pages.  There's lots of info on enabling social logins, just not retrieving the providers for setting up a unified login page or a manage logins page.

Comment: Maybe post an issue to their GitHub? https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need [`SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#replace-getexternalauthenticationschemes)?

```
var loginProviders = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        <div>
            <p>
                @foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I have searched and searched, but hadn't found that page.  Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome! I just created new website in VS and looked into Login.cshtml